# Some purchases NOT showing up on my Apple TV (4K)

Tags: television, 4k

Numerous shows that I have purchased are NOT showing up on my Apple TV.  I have tried logging out then logging back in, but still they do not show up.

They are on my iPhone and iPad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a [Customer Support](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) issue as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are signed into the same Apple ID username (email) and password. If you are, sign out and then sign back in to see if that helps. If that still doesnt work, then you may need to call Apple Care tech support for account assistance.